# typo3: issue with changing file:ext_tables_static+adt.sql

Tags: typo3

In file: `ext/quick/ext_tables_static+adt.sql`

```
    ...
    INSERT INTO `tx_quick_string` (`name`, `vlaue`) VALUES
    ('catalog', 'this is group one');
    ...
```

I want to change the `value` to `'this is group 1'`. This is what I did:

a.changed it in this file:`ext/quick/ext_tables_static+adt.sql`

b.changed it in typo3/phpmyadmin->table `tx_quick_string`

It seems work. But I have some questions:

1.Does this file `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` only take effect when install/uninstall extension?

2.Is there anything else I need to do after I changed the value in `ext_tables_static+adt.sql` and `typo3/phpmyadmin->table tx_quick_string`? Do I need to update the extension in EM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, only when you install the extension.
2. No, if you already did the db update manually, there is nothing more to do.

If the extension you mentioned is not maintained by you, the files may get reverted during the next update of this extension, keep that in mind!

Apart from the things you asked I strongly advise you to NOT use the phpmyadmin extension of TYPO3. It has security problems on a kind of regular basis. So the better and more secure solution is to either use the db management tool your hosting company provides (they will keep it running and updated) or to put a separate tool somewhere else and secure it with a password (like htaccess restriction or something).